# Eclipse properties panel disabled, only popup

Tags: eclipse

I have had a problem with Eclipse which makes the properties panel options disabled. It usually got fixed after Eclipse restart, but after updating to the latest version of Eclipse and plugins using Help -> Check for updates, I can no longer insert text in the properties panel. For example, I'm working on an Android project at the moment. I wanted to insert a LinearLayout in my application and set it's orientation to horizontal. I couldn't type this in the window so I had to open the XML file and insert the property there.

As you can see in the image, these input fields are all greyed out except for the one I have manually inserted in the code.

[image]

Anyone else noticed this or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the Android SDK. The newest version of Android wasn't working correctly. I changed back to level 18 (from 19, Android 4.4) in the layout view in Eclipse  and it's working again.